# Grouping based on most common value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble trying to group based on the most common value.
The data that I have is:

```
ID  Name
327 TypeA
327 TypeA
327 TypeA
327 TypeB
327 TypeB
327 TypeB
327 TypeB
```

In this case I would want to select ID and the Name "TypeB" as it is the most common value for that ID. So the output would look like:

```
ID  Name
327 TypeB
```

Hopefully someone can help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the `mode` in statistics.  Here is one method:

```
select id, name
from (select id, name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is outputting exactly what I'm after. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

here is how to do it using a group by in a subquery

```
select 
    ID,
    Name 
from 
(
    Select 
        ID,
        Name,
        Count(distinct(Name)) as [Count] 
    from tablename 
    group by 
        ID, 
        Name 
    having Count(distinct(Name)) = MAX(Count(distinct(Name)))
)
```